# Clone HTML elements with JS

Tags: javascript, html, clone

Trying to set up a **Tic-Tac-Toe** board based on JS input with an alert. The alert never shows up, and the HTML is never rendered... what am I missing?

**ALL HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe! (and more...)</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Tic Tac Toe">
  <meta name="author" content="SinSysOnline">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
  <style>
  body{
    font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  }
  td{
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:72px;
  }
  td:last-child{
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  }
  tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom:none;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dashboard">
    <input type="text" value="How large is your grid? (default 3)" size="35" />
</div>
<table id="board">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**ALL JS (minus jQuery)**

```
/* Sadly, there is a very well known algorithm to ensure one NEVER loses at
tic-tac-toe. Ties, perhaps, but if you play right you can NEVER LOSE.
I will not institue this cheap shot into my program, and this will be
a computer vs you. I will add in potential moves :-) */

(function($) {
    function create(x){
        var board = [];
        for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
            var tempArr = [];
            for(var j=0;j<x;j++){ tempArr[j] = ""; }
            board.push(tempArr);
        }
        $('#board tr').clone(x);
        return board;
    }
    var x = prompt("How large would you like your grid? (3-10)");
    var board = create(x);
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried adding the JS to the bottom of my body... just kind of confused here. I know JS inside and out... except for DOM manipulation...

Comment: We don't want "relevant js".  if something isn't working and you're here asking, it means you don't know the source.  Which means it could be in the omitted code you didn't think was "relevant".  Post everything

Comment: which event triggers the prompt?

Comment: If your `prompt` isn't showing up then there is an error that has been omitted from the "Relevant JS"

Comment: @Deryck I wanted to create a reasonable post. I am using no libraries other than JS and jQuery. I will post everything I have in another answer to make it simple, but it is definitely the only relevant JS I have.

Comment: No console errors, I think I'm just missing appending or modifying anything to the DOM...

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: The function compChoice() and userChoice() is never invoked in code above. Can they be removed to simplify the issue?

Comment: Hence the reason I said they were irrelevant because they are future implementations once I know how to manipulate the DOM. But sure. Let me remove them.

Comment: Just want to confirm. The expected behavior is: when HTML page is loaded, a dialog will be prompted and ask "How large would you like your grid...". However, the problem is: this dialog is never prompted. Is that the question?

Comment: Yes. I want the initial prompt to come up, and map the board accordingly. I can repeat this function myself if they need to play more than one game. How can I get a prompt, (and I have the CSS coded to work), to produce a visual board for the EU?

Answer (score 0):

## EDITS

I'll never stop if I don't stop now.  I'm stuck anyway.  Hope this helps you on your way.  Still needs some work (undefined references) but is functional if my fanciness didn't distract me so much:

## [JS Fiddle Demo (not working)](http://jsfiddle.net/GH4Ee/)

### Javascript:

```
(function (window, document, $) {
    var $board = $('#board');
    var x = parseInt(prompt("How large would you like your grid? (3-10)"), 10);
    var taken = [];
    create(x);
    function create(x) {
        var tmp;
        var $tr = $('<tr/>');
        var $td = $('<td/><td/><td/>');
        if (x <= 10 && x >= 3 && typeof x === 'number') {
            for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                tmp = $tr.append($td);
                tmp.clone().appendTo($board);
            }
            $('#board').on('click', 'td', function (evt) {
                var e = evt || window.event;
                var y = $(this).index();
                var z = $(this).parent('tr').index();
                taken = (!taken) ? [y, z] : taken;
                userChoice(y, z, x, this);
            });
        } else {
            alert('You entered an incorrect value.  Try again!');
            return false;
        }
    }

    function userChoice(y, z, x, el) {
        //if($(el).text() !== "") {
        console.log(taken);
        for (var d = 0; d < (x - 1); d++) {
            for (var o = 0, n = 0; o < 3; o++) {
                if ((taken[n].indexOf(y) && taken[n].indexOf(z)) || (taken[n].indexOf(y) && taken[n].indexOf(z))) {
                    alert('Already played that spot.  Nice try.');
                    return false;
                }
                n++;
            }
        }
        taken.push([y, z]);
        $(el).text('O');
        console.log(taken);
        if ((taken.length * taken[taken.length].length) / (x - 1) === 3) {
            alert('No more spaces!  Game over!');
            return false;
        }
        compChoice(x);
    }
    function compChoice(x) {
        console.log(taken);
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random(10) * x);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random(10) * x);

        for (var d = 0; d < (x-1); d++) {
            for (var o = 0, n = 0; o < 3; o++) {
                if ((taken[n].indexOf(a) && taken[n].indexOf(b)) || (taken[n].indexOf(a) && taken[n].indexOf(b))) {
                    compChoice(x);
                }
                n++;
            }
        }
        taken.push([a,b]);
        console.log(taken);
        $board.find('tr:nth-of-type(' + a + ')').find('td:nth-of-type(' + b + ')').text('X');
        if ((taken.length * taken[taken.length].length) === x) {
            alert('No more spaces!  Game over!');
            return false;
        }
    }
})(this, this.document, jQuery, undefined);
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <noscript>
        <input type="text" value="How large is your grid? (default 3)" size="35" />
    </noscript>
</div>
<table id="board"></table>
```

Comment: Yeah, let me wrap it into an anonymous function and see what happens.

Comment: workin with the prompts for me here (and i put some validation in for you too) http://jsbin.com/AHIfOFe/1/

Comment: Fiddle works with prompt (annoying invasive). Hmm, once I can render the HTML I'll feel comfortable, as all of my knowledge is JS code for the most part.

Comment: Well I got that working but I found a slight flaw in the design and now I'm trying to fix it (it was trying to clone the rows the wrong way).

Comment: @NicholasHazel HTML rendering fixed (for the table that is) http://jsbin.com/AHIfOFe/1/

Comment: I'd love to see your solution, but it creates an infinite loop... And the document never actually processes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44369/discussion-between-deryck-and-nicholas-hazel)

Comment: Well I did as much as I could manage.  Stuck on an undefined error now.  I'll let you have a go at it.  Re-edited my post with the updates.  http://jsfiddle.net/GH4Ee/

Answer (score 0):

you didn't do any thing with your cloned element!

if you want to dynamically generate a table

the code should be like this

```
var $board = $('#board');
var td = "<td></td>", $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
function create(x) {
    $board.empty();
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        arr.push(td);
    }
    var $trCloned = $tr.clone().append(arr.join(''));
    for(var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        $board.append($trCloned);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N3Ggc/)

```
// JQuery

function create(board, x)
{
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i != x; i++) row.append ($("<td>x</td>"));     // create a row
    for (i = 0; i != x; i++) $('#'+board).append(row.clone()); // then the board
}

// sample use

var x = window.prompt ("How much, boss?");
create('board', x);

// html

<table id='board' />
```

I've put an 'x' inside the cells so that the board is visible

Comment: The point is to make the board a blank slate :-) Initial board code. I just need to know how to make the board reflect a JS response.

Comment: Well obviously you want an answer to a question you never asked, and unfortunately my mind-reading device has been switched off for maintenance. Better luck next time...

Comment: No, it's my fault for getting such realistic help and assuming you'd walk me through the project :-) Sorry for expecting people to expand the initial question. I whole-heartedly agree that you have been helpful and I thank you for that.

Comment: Right, no hard feelings :)

Answer (score 0):

As Fiddle works, this No-Prompt problem is more like an environment/compatibility/typo issue. The problem can be solved progressively.

1. There is a misuse of jQuery's clone() function, the clone() function accepts boolean type (http://api.jquery.com/clone/) , which means whether or not event handlers will be copied. From the code I guess this is not what you want. Please correct it and try again.
2. On which browser did you test? Does this issue happen on one specific browser, or happens on all browsers in your computer? If it is the latter one, then copy your code (copy the files, not re-type) to someone else' computer and try again.
3. Simplify the JS code and test step by step. First, just leave the prompt() line and delete all else, will it work? Then, add an empty create() function and try again. Then, add something more. Sooner or later, you will find the line which causes the problem.

Please let us know if you deliver the above experiment and find something new.